# jQuery Tables, Clickable Dropdown - multiple hidden rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day programmers,

Being an amateur, I hunted around and found someone who created a very nice jQuery drop-down table.  I found a terrific one...

```
$("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
$("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
$("#report tr:first-child").show();
$("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
});
```

And the CSS...

```
#report { border-collapse:collapse;}
#report h4 { margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#report img { float:left;}
#report ul { margin:10px 0 10px 40px; padding:0px;}
#report th { background:#222222 url(header_bkg.png) repeat-x scroll center left; color:#FFF; padding:3px 8px; text-align:center;}
#report td { background:#111111 none repeat-x scroll top left; color:#000; padding:3px 8px; text-align:center;}
#report tr.odd td { background:#000000 url(row_bkg.png) repeat-x scroll center left; cursor:pointer;}
#report div.arrow { background:transparent url(arrows.png) no-repeat scroll 0px -16px; width:16px; height:16px; display:block;}
#report div.up { background-position:0px 0px;}
```

By itself, it works just fine... you can see the gaming page I use it on at the following link:
http://www.mynextbit.com/Pages/Wreckedified/roster.html

I'm trying to figure out a way to make it to where I could drop down maybe 12 or so rows instead of just one to show a bunch of data about one of those characters in the table.  I did some digging and thought I could re-write the jQuery using the

```
nth-child(12n+0)
```

But couldn't quite pull it off.  Am I on the right track at least or is there a more obvious and simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered that it might be possible to simply start a new table within your rows so you can keep the existing functionality?

Right now your HTML looks a bit like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Character</th><th>iLevel</th><th>And your other columns...</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>CharacterName (Build)</td><td>559</td><td>other column data...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is your hidden data row</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of trying to alter the script so that it hides/shows the next 12 `<tr>` tags you could just create a new table inside your hidden data row...

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Character</th><th>iLevel</th><th>And your other columns...</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>CharacterName (Build)</td><td>559</td><td>other column data...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 4</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 5</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 6</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 7</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 8</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 9</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 10</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 11</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hidden data row 12</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But table are "oldschool" so if you draw a picture of what you want to display we might be able to give you some alternative ways too.

Comment: At work, can't try this out for another few hours... However, I don't care if tables are old-school as long as they display the info I need.  I'll try it, and it absolutely looks like it should work, thanks for the idea :)  I'll mark as correct when I get home and implement it.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work because the .next("tr") doesn't differentiate between the main table and the nested table... I messed around with nth-child some more, but never quite got it to work, and gave up.  I'm gonna read a book and learn a bit more for now.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'll see if I can plug through this when I get home.

Comment: But just messing with the fiddle here at work, I think I'm able to manipulate it the way I want it (such as taking advantage of all the real estate beneath a row, not just the first column)... It works on fiddle, I'll see if I can also get it to work at home later.  I feel like I'm not seeing anything new, but we'll see.  Thanks Ivan for persisting in helping me.

Comment: Ok, it worked.  I spent most of my time manipulating the table, and all the while my problems were in the javascript.  I was not using "#report>tbody>tr" (instead just #report), and it made all the difference in the world.  Thanks for the fiddle, it helped clear things up.  I'll vote correct now :)